# Converting Byte Array to Bitmap android

Tags: java, android

I'am trying convert Byte Array to Bitmap to show in `imageView` in android, I am taking byte data from method but When I run the below function,I am taking null value of Bitmap, how can I take bitmap value from `byte[]` array

```
 private CameraProxy.CameraDataCallBack callBack = new CameraProxy.CameraDataCallBack() {

        @Override
        public void onDataBack(byte[] data, long length) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i(TAG, "length . " + length);

            Log.i("data",""+data);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
            im.setImageBitmap(bitmap);




        }
    };
```

Comment: what's `CameraProxy.CameraDataCallBack`?

Comment: it sdk of my sensor returning code When taking pictures

Comment: is it the sdk public? are you sure that the byte array is argb?

Comment: you can't convert *just any* byte array to bitmap. Are you sure that `byte[] data` is a bitmap byte array?

Comment: how can understand that, it returns me like this "data:{88,84,83,80,82,81, + 1382390 more}"

Comment: https://github.com/onejay09/android_packages_apps_Camera2/blob/master/src/com/android/camera/AndroidCameraManagerImpl.java  have good look at this .you will find your ans.

Comment: it returns me NV21 format ,I solved my problem ,thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

These code works for me.

```
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),                       
            selectedImage);

            img = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            //img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: you are doing exactly opposite of what being asked.